# Debugging Show More Show Less button - Missing Paragraphs of Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

There a 'load more/load less' function running on this page which I'm attempting to debug. https://maes-mynan.cogitoprojectx.com/holiday-homes/the-llewellyn-lodge-lodge/

You can see it the section with the heading "More About The Llewellyn Lodge"

The text is displayed via an Advanced Custom Fields WYSIWYG field [WordPress].

I've been playing around with numbers in lines i.e. `.length>4` with no effect.

As far as I can see, the code is set to truncate the text after the fourth paragraph and on-click show the full text. However, instead of just truncating the text, it seems to remove the fourth paragraph entirely. 
In essence, it displays paragraphs 1 - 3, [misses 4] and then displays paragraph 5 onwards.

I've been changing the value of the number in line e.g. `.length>4` with no effect.

Any help, to stop the paragraph disappearing entirely will be gratefully appreciated.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.read-more2').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).children('p').length > 4) {
      jQuery(this).children('p:lt(3)').show();
      jQuery(this).append('<button class="loadMore btn btn-primary">Show More</button>');
    }
  });
  jQuery('.read-more2').on("click", '.loadMore', function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p:gt(3)').show(); // use gt instead of lt
    jQuery(this).removeClass('loadMore').addClass('loadLess').text('Show Less');
  });
  jQuery('.read-more2').on("click", '.loadLess', function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p:gt(3)').hide(); // use gt instead of lt
    jQuery(this).removeClass('loadLess').addClass('loadMore').text('Show More');
  });
});
```

Comment: `.length` doesn't give you the number of lines. Check what the value is returning.

Comment: He said 4th paragraph and there .length does return number of paragraphs

Comment: you have an error: .live is replaced by .on  - change this code `// Close sticky header on menu item click.
    jQuery('.navbar-collapse a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').live( "click", function() {
        //jQuery( ".navbar-toggle").not( ".collapsed" ).trigger( "click" );
        jQuery('.navbar-collapse').css('height', '0');
        jQuery('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
    });`

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan just corrected that. Any thoughts on how to adapt the load more function, to stop it hiding the 4th paragraph or any recommendations on how to implement the same effect via another method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the reason for SHOWING initially is that all p's are hidden, we need to hide the gt(2) when we toggle.

the code could be shortened by having the button use `.toggle(this.textContent==='Show More')` instead of having two event handlers and two class names

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.read-more2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('p').length > 4) {
      $(this).children('p:lt(3)').show(); // because they were hidden 
      $(this).append('<button class="loadMore btn btn-primary">Show More</button>');
    }
  });
  $('.read-more2').on("click", '.loadMore', function() {
    $(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p').show(); // use p to show all
    $(this).removeClass('loadMore').addClass('loadLess').text('Show Less');
  });
  $('.read-more2').on("click", '.loadLess', function() {
    $(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p:gt(2)').hide(); // use gt 2 instead 
    $(this).removeClass('loadLess').addClass('loadMore').text('Show More');
  });
});
```

```css
.read-more2 > p { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="read-more2">
  <p>p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p>p4</p>
  <p>p5</p>
  <p>p6</p>
</div>  
<div class="read-more2">
  <p>p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p>p4</p>
  <p>p5</p>
  <p>p6</p>
</div>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.read-more-spec').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('ul li').length > 4) {
          $(this).find('ul li:lt(3)').show(); // because they were hidden 
          $(this).append('<button class="loadMore btn btn-primary">Show More</button>');
        }
      });
      $('.read-more-spec').on("click", '.loadMore', function() {
        $(this).parent('.read-more-spec').find('ul li').show(); // use p to show all
        $(this).removeClass('loadMore').addClass('loadLess').text('Show Less');
      });
      $('.read-more-spec').on("click", '.loadLess', function() {
        $(this).parent('.read-more-spec').find('ul li:gt(2)').hide(); // use gt 2 instead 
        $(this).removeClass('loadLess').addClass('loadMore').text('Show More');
      });
    });
```

```css
.read-more-spec ul li { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 read-more-spec black">
  <h3>LODGE FEATURES</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Vaulted ceiling to lounge, kitchen and diner</li>
      <li>Two sets of French doors to the front elevation</li>
      <li>Overhanging eaves with discreet lighting to the external front elevation</li>
      <li>Colour coordinated curtains, blinds and carpets</li>
      <li>Fully fitted country style kitchen with four burner gas hob, built under oven and integrated dishwasher and fridge/freezer</li>
      <li>Centre island/breakfast bar with two high backed chairs</li>
      <li>Utility cupboard with under counter washing machine, condensing dryer, hooks, shelves and boot drying area under boiler</li>
      <li>Solid wood dining table top with four painted white chairs</li>
      <li>One large comfortable sofa and two armchairs &#8211; both in a classical design</li>
      <li>Coffee table and lamp table also feature in the lounge area</li>
      <li>Fireplace mantel and, electric log burner style fire</li>
      <li>5ft King sized bed in master bedroom with gas lift under-bed storage</li>
      <li>Freestanding bedroom furniture which includes large wardrobe, mirror, dressing table, dressing stool and bedside tables</li>
      <li>Ensuite bathroom with tiled corner shower and heated towel rail</li>
      <li>Bath in main bathroom with overhead shower and heated towel rail</li>
      <li>Wall mirrors in both bathrooms</li>
      <li>TV points in lounge and master bedroom</li>
      <li>Energy efficient A Rated boiler with radiators and central heating throughout</li>
      <li>Built to British Standard 3632 &#8211; residential specification</li>
      <li>Timber frame structure</li>
      <li>10 year structural warranty</li>
      <li>Horizontal Sierra Canexel Cladding to the exterior for easy maintenance</li>
      <li>Anthracite grey UPVC double glazed doors and windows</li>
      <li>Large decking in complementing grey composite board and handrail with two lockable gates (ideal for dog owners) to front and side. Steps down into the side garden area</li>
<!--       <button class="loadMore btn btn-primary">Show More</button>  -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @mplugjan. How would I also apply this to a <ul> list that appear further down the same page?

Comment: I've tried with <li> however that doesn't appear to work.  I should add; the <ul> list is generated from text contained within a custom field. The markup is: <div class="col-md-6 read-more-spec black"> <h3>LODGE FEATURES</h3> <div> <?php echo $text11; ?> </div> </div>

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan - it seems left out the 'li' from the style.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: My style was .read-more-spec ul { display:none } instead of .read-more-spec ul li { display:none }

Comment: And does it work now or not? I do not know what your comments mean. Good? Bad? Errors?

Comment: In summary, the script works fine, thank you for that.  It was simply that I hadn't correctly added the display: none value to the correct tag in my stylesheet. i.e. I was setting the unordered list as display: none, rather than the list items. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes now it does